# WPF Datagrid Edit won't allow me to change other cells

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, edit, dataview

I've a Datagrid whose DataContext is assigned to a Dataview. When I try to edit the datagrid shown in the form there appears a red border around the cell being editted AFTER I click out or press Enter. 
I then try double clicking on another cell but it won't allow me to be in edit mode.

I've tried following http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/01/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell/ and http://codefluff.blogspot.com/2010/05/commiting-bound-cell-changes.html but neither appear to work on my case.

My Code for the CellEditEnding event

```
 private void dgCompList_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isManualEditCommit)
        {
            isManualEditCommit = true;                
            System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid = (System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid)sender;
            grid.CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);
            isManualEditCommit = false;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried using CommitEdit() on the actual datagrid itself, but nada. Could someone explain to me what's going on and how to resolve this please?

Comment: a read border around it after editing sounds like an error handling/validating issue

Comment: @Muad'Dib Oh my god, thank you ever so much! It was indeed a validating issue (I was passing a string into a int type column). I really wish it threw up an error instead of having some red border!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally, a red border around the cell is a error state, so it sounds like you have some type of validation error, to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you know how to check the datatype of a column in a datatable/datarowview before I can pass through an edit?

Comment: I believe there is an event that fires that you can hook into, but I am not really sure off the top of my head how to do it